# How to make user realise the Drag Drop functionality

Tags: gui-design, users, drag-n-drop

I searched a lot but I did not get any solution.

> **Brief Description**

I have a website which has some elements which are clickable and rest works on drag and drop  funcionality.

Everything works good .

**Problem**

Now Question is How will I make my client realise that so and so element are clickable and so and so has to be dragged and dropped to specific area.

**Possible** *average* **Solution**

One solution is I can give a tour using popups (the way gmail does). But even this does not make my website very user friendly.

I just went through [**stackoverflow tour**](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) .. those animations are also very impressive . Can it done in my case. The moment user scrolls down ,. a basic drag and drop step is shown and restore back the step.

Any suggestions from you smart guys.?

Comment: Why have a drag-drop at first place? It is almost never comfortable to use them, especially on touch devices.

Comment: @gurvinder372 : drag drop is the requirement of the project... the location where elements are dropped are very crutial so can't achieve that using clicks.

Comment: Please share what the user is suppose to achieve with drag and drop.

Answer (score 3):

For a desktop application, I would change the mouse pointer to the move icon (CSS is `cursor: move`), and when the item has been grabbed for dragging, change its background-color to indicate that it has been selected and is draggable. Also give it a shadow so it looks like a separate layer.

And [add animation](https://www.google.com/design/spec/animation/meaningful-transitions.html) to make it more obvious that it is draggable - perhaps a slight bounce when the page loads, or a slight movement in the direction that people are most likely to drag it.

Answer (score 1):

To add to Yvonne's solution:

- Highlight the **draggable object** onMouseOver so as to indicate that it is
  *actionable*
- Popup a *ToolTip comment* like "You can drag & drop this"
- You might also (more complex programming challenge):  Highlight the **target area**.  This
  is most effective if there is only one target.

and Mirror the info:

- Highlight the **target area** onMouseOver  so as to indicate that it is
  *actionable*
- Popup a *ToolTip comment* like "You can drag & drop *into* this"
- You might also (more complex programming challenge):  Highlight the **draggable
  object**.  This is most effective if there are not a whole lot of
  draggable objects.

This robust UI shows you the Realm of Drag&Drop *at a glance* - instantly, no matter where you start.

Value-added:
If you have an on-screen message like "**Drag & Drop**", this could be enabled so that onMouseOver it hilites both *draggable objects* and *target*.